# mvc post using javascript and display result without complete postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, post

I have a mvc page where the user select values from 3 different dropdown lists and then enter a number in a textfield, based on those selections and the entered number I want to do some calculations and then display the result to the user without the whole page being posted again. I understand that this can be solved using javascript, but I'm not to good in writing javasript so I could use some help here on what I need to add in order to get this to work. When I click the sumbmit button the page reloads and it does not enter the "DoCalculation" method... What am I doing wrong here?

```
<form name="myForm">
<div class="form-section col-md-12">
<h3 class="title_contanier">1: </h3>
@Html.DropDownList("PrintType", ViewData["printType"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="form-section col-md-12">
<h3 class="title_contanier">2: </h3>
@Html.DropDownList("Papper", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "-", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>


<div class="form-section col-md-12">
<h3 class="title_contanier">3: </h3>
@Html.DropDownList("PapperType", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "-", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<h3 class="title_contanier">Antal: </h3>
<input type="text" placeholder="Skriv in antal" name="Qty" id="Qty">
<button type="button" id="submitBtn">skicka</button>

<span id="resultMessage"></span>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#PrintType').change(function ()
    {
        $.getJSON('/Home/GetPapperByTypeId/?typeId=' + $('#PrintType').val(), function (data)
        {
            var items = '<option>Välj papper..</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, printtype)
            {
                items += "<option value='" + printtype.Value + "'>" + printtype.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $('#Papper').html(items);
        });
    });

    $('#Papper').change(function ()
    {
        $.getJSON('/Home/GetOptions/?ppai=' + $('#Papper').val() + '&tid=' + $('#PrintType').val(), function (data)
        {
            var items = '<option>Välj option</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, pappertype)
            {
                items += "<option value='" + pappertype.Value + "'>" + pappertype.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $('#PapperType').html(items);
        });
    });
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document)
    .ready(function($) {
        $('#submitBtn').on("click", function () {
            var papper = $('#Papper :selected').val();
            var papperType = $('#PapperType :selected').val();
            var qty = $('#Qty').val();

            var request = {
                "method": "POST",
                "url": "@Url.Content("/Home/DoCalculation/")",
                "data": { "Order": { "Papper": papper, "PapperType": papperType, "Qty": qty } }
            }

            $.ajax(request)
                .success(function(response) {
                    if (response.success == true) {
                        $('#resultMessage').text(response.result);
                    }
                });
        });
    })
 </script>



public ActionResult Index()
{
ViewData["printType"] = Repository.GetAllPrintingTypes();
return View();
}

public class PapperOrder
{
public string Papper { get; set; }
public string PapperType { get; set; }
public int Qty { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult DoCalculation(PapperOrder order)
{
var papper = order.Papper;
var papperType = order.PapperType;
var qty = order.Qty;
var model = new CalculatedPrice { Totalsum = qty };
return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by simple JQuery AJAX request .

```
var papper = $('#Papper :selected').val();
var papperType = $('#PapperType :selected').val();
var qty = $('#Qty').val();

var request = {
  "method" : "POST",
  "url"    : "@Url.Content("ControllerName/DoCalculation")",
  "data"   : { "Order":{ "Papper" : papper,"PapperType":papperType,"Qty" : qty}},
}

$.ajax(request)
 .success(function(response){
 //do whatever you want to do with data
})
```

You can also make things easier by creating a model on your server side, call it PapperOrder

```
    public class PapperOrder {

    public string Papper {get;set;}
    public string PapperType {get;set;}
    public int Qty {get;set;}
  }
```

Now update your controller as follows

```
  public ActionResult DoCalculation(PapperOrder order){
      var Papper = order.Papper;
      var PapperType = order.PapperType;
      var Qty = order.Qty;
   // do further calculations here
  }
```

As you asked how to display the calculated result in success method than follow the following points.

1. You must return Json from your controller action "DoCalculation" like below

   ```
      public ActionResult DoCalculation(PapperOrder order){

        //after calculation

        return Json(new {success = true, result = "12 (or whatever your calculated value is)"});
      }
   ```

Now inside your AJAX success method you can do anything, I suppose that you want to display the result inside a div so create that div

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

and inside your success method

```
   success:function(response){
     if(response.success == true){
        $('#result').text(response.result);
      }
    }
```

Comment: If I try the above code I can see that the "DoCalculation" is triggered when the page loads for the first time. Of course there are no values for the order object yet, but even after I post the form there are no values for the Order object in the DoCalculation method. Also, what do I need to add for the success part of the javascript in order to display the calculated result of DoCalculation?

Comment: Yes it is normal, to get rid of this either use Ajax.BeginForm or remove the Razor helper and enclose your form inside <form></form> html tag.

Comment: @MTplus I will answer the second part of your question I am editing my answer ...

Comment: do I use a Html.BeginForm or Ajax.BeginForm? Right now when I click the submit button the whole page is reloaded and the DoCalculation is not triggered..

Comment: 1. Use Ajax.BeginForm 
2. Remove the type="submit" from the submit button and set it type="button" and also give an id= "submitBtn"
3. Register a click event on the Button like below
$('#submitBtn').on("click",function() {
    //here paste the whole jqueyr ajax request I have posted above.
});

Comment: Or make things simple, remove ajax.begin form and enclose your form in simple form tag as 
<form name="somename"> //your input fields </form> and everything should work fine,

Comment: I have changed it now and edited my original post. It almost works now. The DoCalculation method is triggered when I click the button, but no data is diplayed in the "<div id="resultMessage"></div>"..

Comment: inside the success function write debugger; before anything else and see what you receive in response..

Comment: response.message = "undefined"...

Comment: what does 'response' object contains, also make sure that your server is sending the correct data i.e. a json object which contains 'message' key..

Comment: The DoCalculation method is as in my original post, is that what you wanted to know? Or how can look for errors?

Comment: put a break point on your DoCalculationMethod inside Visual Studio and see if the request is being made or not. then put a break point inside success method that what is being recieved inside response object.. also when u make the request check the network tab inside the developer console to see the status of your request i.e. is it successfull or not

Comment: I got what you meant no, I added the Success propery now to my model and then it all worked. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: great..don't forget to upvote.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all instead of Html.BeginForm use Ajax.BeginForm

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DoCalculation", "YourControllerName", null new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "yourHandleResponseFunction"}, new { id = "myForm", name = "form_search" }))
{
    <div class="form-section col-md-12">
      <h3 class="title_contanier">1: </h3>
      @Html.DropDownList("PrintType", ViewData["printType"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-section col-md-12">
      <h3 class="title_contanier">2: </h3>
      @Html.DropDownList("Papper", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "-", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>


    <div class="form-section col-md-12">
      <h3 class="title_contanier">3: </h3>
      @Html.DropDownList("PapperType", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "-", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <h3 class="title_contanier">Antal: </h3>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Skriv in antal" name="Qty" id="Qty">
    <button type="submit" class="btn_submit_quick_search btn_submit_search pull-right" name="btn_submit_section_search_id_mls">calculate</button>

    <span id="resultMessage"></span>
}

<script>
    function yourHandleResponseFunction(data)
    {
       //process your data here
       $('#resultMessage').html(data.Totalsum);
    }
</script>
```

Of course response data structure has to match to the one that you sent from server:

```
public ActionResult DoCalculation(PapperOrder order)
{
    var papper = order.Papper;
    var papperType = order.PapperType;
    var qty = order.Qty;
    var model = new CalculatedPrice { Totalsum = qty };
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex,if I only use what you suggested nothing happends at all after a submit the form, how is the DoCalculation method triggered?

Comment: I have updated to what I currently have that does not work, the DoCalculation method is not triggered...

Comment: You need to put DoCalculation url into ajax form. See updated answer and replace YourControllerName with the actual controller name

Comment: also remove the ajax related javascript - Ajax.BeginForm does all this for you.

Comment: Ok, if I do that and submit the form the DoCalculation is triggered and I can see the forma values correct. But the only thing displayed on the page after postback is the json result..... I need to keep the whole page and just update a span element on the page with the calculated value.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `Ajax.BeginForm` and not `Html.BeginForm`?

Comment: just use the code in my answer without as is ( do replace `YourControllerName` with the actual controller name). Remove all the JavaScript that posted in your question.

Comment: yes I use the Ajax.BeginForm and I have replaced YourControllerName with "Home" and also use your javascript. When I click submit the Docalculation is triggered but then a blank page is displayed with just the result of the calculation made in "DoCalculation"...

Comment: I think that you still have some JS that posts the whole form back. Can you try to remove all the classes and name from submit button so it looks like this:
`<button type="submit" class="pull-right" >calculate</button>`

Comment: I removed all names and classes from both the form and the submit button now but still get the blank page after submit...

Comment: The weird thing is that I on the page has 2 javascript functions that fetch data to dropdownlists depending on a selection in dropdown list like this "$.getJSON('/Home/GetPapperByTypeId/?typeId=' + $('#PrintType').val(), function (data)" and they work... Its just this part that does not work as expected

Comment: This issue is not in caused by the code you posted

Comment: Ok, I have no idea whats causing this issue.... I guess I have to use another approach then...

Comment: try to remove id and name from form itself. maybe you have some event handlers registered on this form

Comment: Thta I allready have done, it did not help...